# How to display more than one website on a webView

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, webview

I have a Recycler View and I want my webView to display different website when different items on the Recycler View is clicked.

I have implemented a recycler view which has An ImageView, and two text views. I want a website to be opened in the webview anytime an item on the recycler view is clicked. I want different websites to be opened anytime an item from different rows on the recycler view is clicked.

I have tried different methods but its still not working.

These are my codes

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

private ArrayList<String> mImageViews  = new ArrayList<>();
private  ArrayList<String> mBlogDescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mBlogNames = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
public RecyclerViewAdapter mViewAdapter;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> imageViews, ArrayList<String> blogDescriptions,ArrayList<String> blogNames, Context context) {
    mImageViews = imageViews;
    mBlogDescriptions = blogDescriptions;
    mBlogNames = blogNames;
    mContext = context;

    }

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");
    String currentItem = mBlogNames.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageViews.get(position))
            .into(holder.mImageView);


    holder.mBlogDescription.setText(mBlogDescriptions.get(position));
    holder.mBlogName.setText(mBlogNames.get(position));
    holder.mBlogName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putStringArray("url", new String[]{"www.goal.com","www.facebook.com","www.twitter.com","www.youtube.com"});
            extras.get(String.valueOf(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mBlogDescriptions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CircleImageView mImageView;
    TextView mBlogDescription;
    TextView mBlogName;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.circular_image);
        mBlogDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_description);
        mBlogName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_name);
        mRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    }
}
}
```

WebViewActivity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] array = extras.getStringArray("url");

    mWebView.loadUrl("array");
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

please help me with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: can you clear a bit more. becauase what i am getting is you want to open a webview  in separate activity which should not be a problem.

Comment: okay, I want to open different urls from a recycler view in a web view. Whenever an item is clicked on the recycler view a website should open on the webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to create different webviews in your recycler view.

**If that is the case i would suggest**

1. creating an android resource file containing the webview
2. creating an array with the different urls you would like to see in the webview.
3. Creating a recyclerview adapter that inflates the recource file with the data inside your array.
4. Pass the adapter into the recycler view.

**If you have the urls set with the views inside your recyclerview. What you need to do is**

1. You should implement onTouchEventLister to your recycler view
2. Then get the view that was touched by getting the view in the position of the touch.
3. Get the data from that view e.g. if the view that was touched was a textview with text as url. You can get the text from it.
4. Update the webview url with the url you got from the textview.

Since the two views are on the same context, you can call them from within the ontoucheventlistener

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response but using this method seems like a lot of work, is there any other simpler method?

Comment: If you are thinking of having so many URLs in the recyclerview that is the way to go.

Comment: Another way you can do this is just create a recyclerview with custom layout that has in it webviews of the different URLs. The recommended way of handling click events on a recyclerview is through the toucheventlistener... Don't be lazy. Take a deep breath and implement it that way :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response, I will try to implement them.

Comment: David Innocent I tried implementing this but it is not working, can you help me with the code to do this.

Comment: I have successfully implemented it, thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
```

```
 CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
            intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            intentBuilder.build().launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
```

I hope this will help you:)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't intend to make use of custom tabs. I will appreciate it if you have any other answer that includes a web View.